# CSS Flex why it fits the space strange?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I put 3 divs into div with display:flex, expecting that it will fit all the space by the real content amount.

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

The live exemple is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/rX3ykWgyTH65uIDHpIS1?p=preview

But in Chrome it seems that the result is not quite as I thought (just like in the table above):

[image].

Is it normal? If is then why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by `margin:auto 10px;` that you have applied to your flex items (selector `.pod > div`).

Or to be more precise, it's caused by the vertical `margin:auto` - this is overriding the stretch effect of flex.

Change the margin to `margin:10px` and it will work.